# Play framework - dependencies.yml not generated automatically

Tags: excel, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am new to play framework. I am using play 2.0. I am trying to generate the excel report for my application. When I eclipsify my application, dependencies.yml is not generated. So I created an explicit dependencies.yml file and included play dependency along with excel module in application.conf. But there is no INFO regarding the excel module available. So I downloaded the excel 1.2.3 zip module and placed in the play directory. Stil no success!!! 
Please give me a solution ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

Play 2.0 uses sbt to manage dependencis. There is no more dependency.yml. See the doc on how to declare dependencies

http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.1/SBTDependencies

Comment: the document doesnot show on how to add dependencies for modules in play 2.0. I tried using


    val appDependencies = Seq(
      "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18",
 "play" % "excel" % "1.2.3"
    )
After updating I am getting sbt.ResolveException : unresolved dependency : play#excel;1.2.3 : not found.

please tell me how to use module dependencies in play 2.0

Answer (score 1):

Also keep in mind that the modules created for Play 1.x Will not work with Play 2.x. It's mentioned at every details page for each module.

`This module is for the Play 1.x series only.`

Currently 2.0 modules are available at: https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/Modules, but there's no excel module yet.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!! So can you please tell me how to generate excel reporting in play 2.0 or it is not possible in Play 2.0 through modules ?

Comment: Use link from Seb Cesborn's link to include Apache POI (add line `"org.apache.poi" % "poi" % "3.8"` to your `appDependencies`) after that perform `play clean-all` + `play update` commands and then you will be able to generate any reports with the library. There's a sample in POI's HOWTO: http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html